# subfigure numbering in subfigure environment (subcaption package)

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

My new friend is the subfigure environment of the subcaption package. Although reading the manual by Axel Sommerfeldt i did not managed to change the subfigure numbering from lower case letters to small Roman numerals.

I need them beside pure personal preference for having the ability to have more than 24 (z) subfigures.

Can somebody assist me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two picures; a black picture (i) and another black picture (ii).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

not desired output:

[image: not desired]

desired output:

[image: desired]

thanks in advance

Benjamin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the representation for the `subfigure` counter by redefining `\thesubfigure`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two picures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b}).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot :-) I dont know why I couldn't figure it out :-(