# A single subfigure with numerical labels

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I am using `subfigure` and want one `figure` to use, instead of `(a),(b)` labels, numbered labels like `(1),(2)`. [subfigure numbering in subfigure environment (subcaption package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123019/subfigure-numbering-in-subfigure-environment-subcaption-package) shows how to get roman numerals using `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}`. Can I adapt this to give numbers?

Also, I just want this to affect one figure. So putting this `\renewcommand` at the beginning of the document in the preamble is not what I want. I thought perhaps I need to put it before my figure, then immediately afterwards I have to switch back to `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}` which gives alphabetical labels. Is this the best way?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Test: \subref{sfig:a1}, \subref{sfig:a}, \subref{sfig:a3}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two picures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a1}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b1}).}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two picures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b}).}
\end{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a3}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two picures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a3}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b3}).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:   insert `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` just after the relevant `\begin{figure}`. This way, the modification will be local to this figure environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Test: \subref{sfig:a1}, \subref{sfig:a}, \subref{sfig:a3}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two pictures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a1}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b1}).}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two pictures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b}).}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 1}
             \label{sfig:a3}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            {\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
            \caption{Picture 2}
             \label{sfig:b3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two pictures; a black picture (\subref{sfig:a3}) and another black picture (\subref{sfig:b3}).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]